# Save MetaFile to Stream and back again

Tags: c#, image, exception, stream, metafile

I need to store a `MetaFile` into a `Stream` and create a new Metafile with the same stream.

I have the following code but it throws an excetpion:

```
string tempPath = Path.GetTempFileName();
MyMetaFile.Save(tempPath);
var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(tempPath));
File.Delete(tempPath);
var newMetafile = new Metafile(stream);  // here the exception
```

The exception message says: `ExternalException: A generic error occured in GDI+`.

I tried also to use the method `Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Emf)` but it throws an exception too.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have recently worked out how to write metafiles to disk.  Perhaps it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560157/how-to-write-an-old-style-metafile-to-a-file


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560157/how-to-write-an-old-style-metafile-to-a-file/25560158#25560158