# How to write an old-style Windows metafile to a file

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

I can generate an old (not enhanced) metafile.  How can I write it to disk so that it is a proper .wmf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Petzold doesn't mention it](http://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heha/petzold/ch18b.htm), but there is a convention for writing metafiles to disk: prefix the metafile data with the [WmfPlaceableFileHeader structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Apparently this was [invented by Aldus, back int the day](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/caolan/ora-wmf.html) and is called a "placeable metafile".

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct WmfPlaceableFileHeader
{
     public uint key;  // 0x9aC6CDD7
     public ushort hmf;
     public ushort bboxLeft;
     public ushort bboxTop;
     public ushort bboxRight;
     public ushort bboxBottom;
     public ushort inch;
     public uint reserved;
     public ushort checksum;
}

Win32.WmfPlaceableFileHeader header = new Win32.WmfPlaceableFileHeader();
const ushorttwips_per_inch = 1440;
header.key = 0x9aC6CDD7;  // magic number
header.hmf = 0;
header.bboxLeft = 0;
header.bboxRight = width_in_inches * twips_per_inch;
header.bboxTop = 0;
header.bboxBottom = height_in_inches * twips_per_inch;
header.inch = twips_per_inch;
header.reserved = 0;

// Calculate checksum for first 10 WORDs.
ushort checksum = 0;
byte[] header_bytes = StructureToByteArray(header);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     checksum ^= BitConverter.ToUInt16(header_bytes, i * 2);
header.checksum = checksum;

// Construct the file in-memory.
header_bytes = StructureToByteArray(header);
file_contents.Write(header_bytes, 0, header_bytes.Length);
file_contents.Write(metafile_bytes, 0, metafile_bytes.Length);
```

Comment: Just curious - what program are you catering to that needs such an old data format?

Comment: I'm generating metafiles for export to PowerPoint.  I can generate enhanced metafiles, but the background does not show through (is opaque), whereas with old-style ones the undrawn area is transparent.

Comment: If you don't plan to scale the image, you may want to investigate whether a PNG suffices.

Comment: Actually I am working on the metafkles because the png's have not worked that well: not sharp when printing (even when resolution doubled) and transparency causes nasty defects at the edges of text.

Comment: Turns out we could get transparent enhanced metafiles working.  May have been an issue with an older version of Office.  Anyway, it was fun working this out.